# Display the result of a stored procedure in a Recordset on a form

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

The following code run a stored procedure based on a combobox that is selected in a form. I need to display the results in a form in Access. Here is the code:

```
Dim Cmd1 As ADODB.Command
Dim lngRecordsAffected As Long
Dim rs1 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim intRecordCount As Integer
'-----
Dim cnnTemp As ADODB.Connection
Set cnnTemp = New ADODB.Connection
cnnTemp.ConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=****;" & _
"Trusted_Connection=No;UID=****;PWD=****;" & _
"Initial Catalog=IKB_QA;"
'Open Connection
cnnTemp.Open
Set Cmd1 = New ADODB.Command
Cmd1.ActiveConnection = cnnTemp
'---
With Cmd1
Dim localv As Integer
localv = [Forms]![start]![Selection]![cat_code]
.CommandText = "dbo.ix_spc_planogram_match"
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
.Parameters.Refresh
.Parameters("@catcode").Value = localv

Set rs1.Open = Cmd1.Execute(localv)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: And what issue are you having?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Kindly read the [FAQ] -- what you've written sounds more like a work description, or a code request, than an actual question. Phrasing your question _like a question_ and explaining specifically where you are stuck is more likely to result in you getting the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me which part of this problem you're having trouble with but maybe it's the binding part.

You can bind a form to an ADO recordset using the following code:

```
Set Me.Recordset = rs1
```

Just make sure your form has controls on it bound to the fields which will be in your recordset.